# Articles listed in order base upon "Last-edit Date" instead of "Publishing Date"

Tags: views

I have to solve a small bug in a Drupal **7.31** installation.

I have 3 rows in homepage, in which are listed 3 articles for each of them. Here a partial screenshot of `Edit View` for the first row, in wich **Sort criteria** is set to "*Publishing Date*".

[image]

In "Auto preview" pane, in the bottom area of this page, sorting seems corresponding to "*Publishing Date*" (node IDs are respectevely: "node-1901", "node-1861", "node-1904"), while when I load Homepage in browser, order is "node-1861", "node-1901", "node-1904".

It seems that in a case, order is made by "*Last-edit Date*" and not "*Publishing Date*".

How to make them coherent and, most important, how to display articles in Homepage in "*Publishing Date*" order ignoring "*Last-edit Date*"?

Answer (score 0):

By your description, it seems to me that there's some code in your theme implementing a views hook or a theme hook, and doing a custom ordering before rendering the results (either altering the query, or altering the results after the query). The following hooks could do that:

- hook_views_pre_execute()
- hook_views_post_execute()
- hook_views_pre_render()

plus the [theme_preprocess_views_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7)

I'd suggest having a look at the theme to see if any of those is implemented, and is getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal core and Views you get two dates associated with nodes 'Content: Post date' and 'Content: Updated date'.

Post date is the date of creation of the node, Updated date is the date of last save.